# MVVM model with collections. Use or not observablecollection in model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, mvvm-light

I'm struggling with one point of MVVM and I hope someone can enlighten me.

My scenario is this:
A model something like this:

```
public class Codes
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubCoddes> SubCodes { get; set; }
}
```

A ViewModel that has this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Codes> Codes { get; set; }
```

The `Codes` collection are bound to a `ListView` in the View.

My big doubt is if there should be ObservableCollection in the model. If not, what is a better approach?

Both `Codes` and `SubCodes` are filled by a query in a MS SQLServer database when the application is initialized...and there's no option to create new ones. They can only be reused.

I can have in `Codes` multiple equal codes with different values - ex:

```
Code a = new Code { value="test1", Code ="100" }
Code b = new Code { value="test2", Code ="100" }
```

These values should be bound to `TestBox`es in the view.

====EDIT=====

Maybe I have wrongly exposed the problem. When I say cannot create more, I may have lead to a wrong preposution. What I meant is that the initial structure is created with the DB query, but in the UI there will be buttons to replicate a Code and a Subcode...and that will add those to the corresponding lists.

Ex: in the UI:

Code A - duplicate button

->  Subcode A - duplicate button

->  Subcode B - duplicate button

Code B - duplicate button

Everytime I click on a duplicate button it duplicates the structure (either subcodes or codes with subcodes).

These changes must be done in the  bservableCollection Codes.

I hope I'm making myself clear...and sorry for my English.

Regards

Comment: The "Best" approach architecturally would be to separate your view model layer from your model layer. Practically, unless you're doing heavy lifting in your app it is ok to 'mix' the two. Also note, if it _is_ observable you don't have to expose it to the outside, you can have an `ICollection<SubCodes>` property and just assign it to an `ObservableCollection` when you create it - that way irrelevant users of the code don't have to be aware.

Comment: I've been reading for the last 4hours...and I get to nowhere mainly because the separation of concerns in VM and Model. I have multiples hierarchical classes (A class has many B that has many C and so long), and all of them represent items in a treeviewlist. I understand that PropertyChanged should be dealt in VM, but in this scenario I think that it should be in Model...or am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need an `ObservableCollection<T>` that is only useful when you add or remove items from the collection after assigning it - which you say you do not. A `List<T>` would be fine and well within MVVM. However you still have to remember to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.100).aspx) and raise the `PropertyChanged` when the `List<T>` is assigned - or anything you assign you want the binding to re-read the source.

e.g. you should have:

```
private List<Code> codes;
public List<Codes> Codes 
{ 
    get {return codes;}
    set 
    {
        codes = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Codes");
    }
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The same applies to your nested collection SubCodes, i.e. `Codes` should also implement the interface and the setter for SubCodes should raise the event. Furthermore if you were to modify a `Code`'s property at runtime and you want that reflected in the UI the properties on `Code` should raise the event too. Also any class you bind to should always implement the interface even if the individual properties do not raise the event, [because binding to a class that does not implement the interface creates memory leaks.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938416) (unless the Property is a DependencyProperty, which it shouldn't be unless you are authoring you own control, or the Binding Mode is OneTime).

Comment: This will only notify when the `List<Code>` is updated with a new `List<Code>`; is that what you're describing?

Comment: When YourViewModel.Codes is assigned, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure this is applicable, the OP specifically said: "_Both Codes and SubCodes are filled by a query in a MS SQLServer database when the application is initialized...and there's no option to create new ones. They can only be reused._" In other words, if the collections will never be created again, why use INotifyPropertyChanged on the backing collection?

Comment: 1.) Not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged leads to memory leaks if you bind to that class, 2.) The query could (should) be asynchronous so will not be assigned till after the view is loaded so if you want the view updated once the query has finished you have to! Even if it weren't asynchronous relying on the implementation detail that assigning to it early on generally works shouldn't be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

I think the MVVM way is to have the entities/data model in the Model, and to do all the tweeks and modifications to it in the ViewModel so it can then bind it to the View. Assuming you are using observable collections to check if the user modifies some textbox maybe they should be in the ViewModel.