# Is it bad practice to access viewmodel from view's class?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mvvm, maui

I am developing an app with.NET MAUI. For the desktop app, I am using each segment of the app for different data and such. I either had to use prism region navigation or try to do it with the built-in MAUI functions. I didn't use Prism, but the way I implemented the app meant that I often had to call viewmodel functions from view's class.

Is this bad? Right now, I can't think of another way, but if it is a critical problem, I will try to find another way before moving forward.

**EDITED:**

```cs
private async void DeleteButtonTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (answer)
    {
        var bindingContext =  BindingContext as AgentDetailsPageViewModel;
        await bindingContext.DeleteFromDatabase();
        var agentsViews = this.Parent as Grid;
        agentsViews.Remove(this);
        var parentBorder = agentsViews.Parent as Border;
        parentBorder.IsVisible = false;
        var parentGrid = parentBorder.Parent as Grid;
        var agentsBorder = parentGrid.Children[0] as Border;
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(agentsBorder, 2);
        var parentBindingContext = parentGrid.BindingContext as AgentsPageViewModel;
        parentBindingContext.Populate();
    }
}
```

for example the code above is a situation that i am using the viewmodel in view's class. i'm calling the delete database and populate from my viewmodel but i'm not passing any data.

```cs
ObservableCollection<string> creditCardEntries = new ObservableCollection<string>();
foreach (var creditCardborderStack in creditCardbordersStack)
{
    var grid = creditCardborderStack.GetChildren<Grid>().FirstOrDefault();
    var entry = grid.GetChildren<Entry>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (entry.Text is not null)
    {
        if (entry.Text.ToCharArray()[4] != '-')
        {
            creditCardEntries.Add(Regex.Replace(entry.Text, @"(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})", @"$1-$2-$3-$4"));
        }
        else
        {
            creditCardEntries.Add(entry.Text);
        }
    }
}
var bindingContext = (AgentAddOrEditPageViewModel)BindingContext;
if (bindingContext.AgentCreditCardNumbers is not null)
{
    bindingContext.AgentCreditCardNumbers.Clear();
}
bindingContext.AgentCreditCardNumbers = creditCardEntries;
if (await bindingContext.AddToDatabase())
{
    CloseViewAfterInsertion();
}
```

this is another part of my code and i'm very concerned about this part. basically user can insert infinite credit card numbers. I could not figure out a way to bind them to the viewmodel because eveytime a user wants too add a new credit card i create a textbox in the ui and i could not generate the viewmodel property dynamically to bind it to the textbox.

now if you look at my code you can see that i search through the ui the find the textboxes and get their values. i create a string collection and pass the string collection to my viewmodel. after that i get values and i insert them my CreditCard Class and i do the insertion.

I personally think this is not good but i cannot figure out another way so if you guys have suggestion that might salvage this situation i will be very greatfull.

Comment: *" i search through the ui the find the textboxes and get their values."* This part is dubious. Not because its any MVVM violation, but because its almost never necessary to grab values from UI elements Each of those textboxes' Text should be a `Binding` to some string property. Then write a function that gets the values from those properties. For more specific advice, add to question the xaml for one of those textboxes.

Comment: I am on the same page with you but is there a way to create or destroy a property on the viewmodel? and after that can i bind the created property to a new textbox in view? because my users can add unlimited phone numbers and i can't pre define every property in the view model. so i have to find a way to create the string property dynmically to bind it to the view. i searched a lot in internet i couldn't find my answer so i had to improvise. for the code it is not much different from the delete button event that i posted. i get the parent and children of elements till i reach the part i want.

Comment: In that case, I would create the entries in code behind. Hold them in  class instance members. In list, dictionary, or a custom data class. Would not search, because would know exactly where they are; would have references to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see if its bad, you would have to share more information with us, maybe an example of how the access looks like, that you think might be bad.

But generally spoken:

In MVVM, the View accesses the ViewModel, and the ViewModel accesses the Model

```
V -> VM -> M
```

So no, it is not a bad practice to access the ViewModel from the View *for which the ViewModel was made*.

### but:

The View and the ViewModel usually belong together. And, the ViewModel should contain no real business logic, but only abstracts the things that the (one) View has to display, and delegate functions and manipulations down to the model.

So: If you would access a ViewModel *that does not belong to that View*, or even use reusable ViewModels as "model-acess-wrappers", because it already has the correct methods you need to manipulate or read the model, then it would be very wrong.

Comment: hey micheal thanks for your complete answer i edited my post can you check it out now? based on what you said i am very concerned about a part of my code breaking the mvvm concept

Comment: Using Viewmodel in the Views class is okay, (its called "code behind"). You should try to avoid it, solve most tasks with databinding, (commands, etc), but to code the UX of the view in the "code behind" or special situations, thats pretty normal. (scrollbars, )..  

its not pretty, but i dont see any architectural flaws here (violation of application layers) and i dont see any illegal usage of viewmodel here, assuming the first code part is in the "AgentDetails"View and 2nc code part in "Add/edit" View) . what i definitely see is that you use observable collection wrong in the 2nd method

Comment: oh that is a relief. can you tell more about my observable collection mistake.

Comment: its too long a story for a comment, but check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21977393/7231339